# How to create css folder working both locally and thru GAE?

Tags: google-app-engine

I have the following folders structure:

```
project-folder
 - templates
   - css
     vk.css
   index.html
 app.yaml
 script.py
```

I would like to be able:

1. run index.html without GAE
2. run index.html thru GAE (referenced at `script.py` as `templates/index.html`)

In both cases `vk.css` should be used. How should I define that at `app.yaml` and at `index.html`? Url is `http://localhost:8080/something/`.

I've made it working with GAE, `index.html`:

```
<link type="text/css" href="/css/vk.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

`app.yaml`:

```
- url: /css/
  static_dir: templates/css
```

But it doesn't work locally.

Comment: What do you mean with locally? On a normal web server or just opening the page?

Answer (score 1):

If you want your browser to be able to render the template directly off the filesystem, you can't use site-relative URLs (eg, ones that begin with a `/`) - when reading off your filesystem, site relative URLs are relative to your filesystem root. Instead, use relative urls (eg, `../css/vk.css`), and make sure that the filesystem structure matches your URL structure.